# How to change font color on Mouse enter and Mouse Exit in java

Tags: java, swing, mouseover, jbutton

I am Doing an Swing Application.I want to Change Text Color of the Buttons on **MouseEntered** and **MouseExited**.

```
private void jButton2MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
      this.jButton2.setBackground(Color.red); 
    }                                     
    private void jButton2MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
       this.jButton2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    }
```

This is How i am Changing Background Color. How to Change Text color of the Button.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Button.setForeground(Color.red);` method to set a new font color.

```
private void jButton2MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
      this.jButton2.setBackground(Color.red); 
      this.Button.setForeground(Color.red);
    }                                     
    private void jButton2MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
       this.jButton2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
       this.Button.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
    }
```

Comment: Well my navigator loaded the other answer first, very odd :\.